# Regex - Extract second position digit from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex:

```
var thisMatch = Regex.Match(result, @"(?-s).+(?=[\r\n]+The information appearing in this document)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This returns the line before "The information appearing in this document" just fine.
The output of my regex is

```
10 880 $10,000 $800 $25 $10
```

I need to extract 880, which will always be in second position (the number before 880 could be vary, so \d{0,2} shouldn't be allowed).

How can I grab the second position number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```cs
(?<=^\S+[\p{Zs}\t]+)\d+(?=.*[\r\n]+The information appearing in this document)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5CS%2B%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%2B%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D.*%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2BThe%20information%20appearing%20in%20this%20document%29&i=10%20880%20%2410%2C000%20%24800%20%2425%20%2410%0D%0AThe%20information%20appearing%20in%20this%20document). In C#:

```cs
var output = Regex.Match(result, @"(?<=^\S+[\p{Zs}\t]+)\d+(?=.*[\r\n]+The information appearing in this document)", RegexOptions.Multiline)?.Value;
```

Or, you could capture the number and grab it from a group with

```cs
^\S+[\p{Zs}\t]+(\d+).*[\r\n]+The information appearing in this document
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5CS%2B%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%2B%28%5Cd%2B%29.*%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2BThe%20information%20appearing%20in%20this%20document&i=10%20880%20%2410%2C000%20%24800%20%2425%20%2410%0D%0AThe%20information%20appearing%20in%20this%20document). In C#:

```cs
var output = Regex.Match(result, @"^\S+[\p{Zs}\t]+(\d+).*[\r\n]+The information appearing in this document", RegexOptions.Multiline)?.Groups[1].Value;
```

*Regex details*:

- `(?<=` - start of a positive lookbehind that requires its pattern to match immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `^` - start of a line (due to the `RegexOptions.Multiline`)
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `[\p{Zs}\t]+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `\d+` - one or more digits (use `\S+` if you are sure this will always be the non-whitespace char streak)
- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead that requires its pattern to match immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line (as `.`  does not match an LF char)
  - `[\r\n]+` - one or more CR/LF chars
  - `The information appearing in this document` - literal text
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

Comment: @davis I will add regex explanation now

Comment: second answer is what I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you insert

```
\d+\s(\d+)
```

this will capture a leading number (`\d+`), separated by a whitespace (`\s`) from the number you're looking for (`(\d+)`), captured in a capture group so you can easily access it.

Check the tab *Split List* in [this online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5CS%2B%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%2B%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D.*%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2BThe%20information%20appearing%20in%20this%20document%29&i=10%20880%20%2410%2C000%20%24800%20%2425%20%2410%0D%0AThe%20information%20appearing%20in%20this%20document)